# Why can't view be resolved

Tags: android

I'm making an app as a part of my school project and I have come across an error to do with 'view'. It says 'view' can't be resolved.

There is also another error to do with R.id.concern and the other ones.
It says a constant expression is required.

The point of this code is to, when a button is pressed, check what checklists have been checked, assign 1 or 0 to it and than add the score. It than changes the text based on score.

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class check_Button extends Pop_sallian{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popwindow_sallian);
        // Connects The variable to an xml id


        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

        //sets the variable to 0
        int score = 0;

        public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.concern:
                if(checked) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.faith:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.respect:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.education:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.community:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
                }
    }





        // adds the variables together to form a score

        if(score == 0){
            output.setText("Come on! Get involved, your la sallian community needs you.");
        } else if(score == 1){
            output.setText("Good start, keep going!");
        } else if(score == 2){
            output.setText("Room to improve but doing good!");
        } else if(score == 3){
            output.setText("Very good, others look up to you!");
        } else if(score == 4){
            output.setText("Wow, you really are an inspiration");
        } else if(score == 5){
            output.setText("Excellent! You're a leader in your la sallian community");
        } else{
            output.setText("Unknown");
        }
        // changes the output text based on score value
    }
}
```

^^code where errors are^^

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 1/27/2016.
 */
public class Pop_sallian extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.popwindow_sallian);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));

        Button checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
        checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Pop_sallian.this, check_Button.class));
            }
        });
        Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton_sallian);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

^^Code where the button checking the check list is^^

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    android:elevation="8dp"

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you a Sallian?"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you meet the following prerequisites, if you do you may be a Sallian"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you concerened for the poor and Social Justice?"
        android:id="@+id/concern"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you have faith in the presence of God?"
        android:id="@+id/faith"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/concern"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you have Respect for all people?"
        android:id="@+id/respect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/faith"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you value education?"
        android:id="@+id/education"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/respect"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you inclusive in your community?"
        android:id="@+id/community"
        android:layout_below="@+id/education"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:id="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_below="@+id/community"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:textColor="#00E676"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:textColor="#00E676"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:textColor="#1eff00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/community"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/check"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

^^Xml code^^

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.who);
        Button today = (Button) findViewById(R.id.today);
        Button sallian = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sallian);
        Button how = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toBe);
        Button moreInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop.class));
            }
        });

        today.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_today.class));
            }
        });
        sallian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_sallian.class));
            }
        });
        how.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_how.class));
            }
        });
        moreInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_info.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

^^Activity main^^

If there are any improvements or other errors you have spotted, feel free to point them out. If you can please include code as a part of your answer.

Comment: Why is android:elevation="8dp" out of all the tags??? :o

Comment: In what line number exactly you are facing error?? and what is the error?? can you please post error logs??

Comment: It's a pop up window and I was attempting to add elevation to it.

Comment: Is it ok to place it outside?? I never used it so curious to know :) can you please confirm the same??

Comment: The elevation attempt didn't work and I just forgot to remove it.

Comment: The errors are between line 28 and 52

Comment: As Sandeep indicates, this:
android:elevation="8dp"

Is not inside element tags which prevents compilation of the constants in "R" and prevents Android from finding the view, resulting in your error message.

Comment: It did fix the previous errors but now there is an error with the score and output

Comment: What is it ??? I have a question is your start Activty working???

Comment: The score variables in the case and break have an error 'cannot resolve symbol' This is at line 34 to 54 and also in line 66 to 76.

Comment: The output also has the same error and this is in line 67 to 79

Comment: The activity main is working

Comment: What line are you getting the error "view can't be resolved"?

Comment: That has been resolved but, there is a new error with the score and output .

Comment: Whay are you trying to extend check_Button with Pop_sallian?? what is your intention?

Comment: I'm new to android and after seeing a bunch of example code I just assumed you had to do that.

Comment: Tell me what are you trying to do when I tap a button in Pop_sallian???

Comment: Pop sallian is a pop up window. When you press the check button it checks what buttons are checked adds 1 or 0 to score depending on whether it's checked or not and than changes the text within the textview(also known as output) depending on the score. The okay button just dismisses the pop up window. Hope that helps.

Comment: ok then check_Button must be having its own screen correct (like activity_check_Button.xml)??? Where is it?? Where are you inflating it in check_Button and retruning it importantly why are you returning content view as R.layout.popwindow_sallian which is same as Pop_sallian???? :o

Comment: Okay button and checkbutton are in the same xml because when the user is finished they can use the check button to check and the okay button to dismiss

Comment: I have written answer assuming what you might be trying to do here :) Please check :) lemme know if any issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following line from :

```
Button sallian = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sallian);
```

To:

```
Button sallian = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton_sallian);
```

Comment: The button sallian is what calls the pop up from the activity main

Comment: @AshrafAli I think the button id in XML and button id in code is not matching, if the XML is of main activity.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first You have declared a method inside another method :)

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

            switch(view.getId()){
                case R.id.concern:
                    if(checked) {
                        score += 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.faith:
                    if(checked){
                        score+=1;
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.respect:
                    if(checked){
                        score+=1;
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.education:
                    if(checked){
                        score+=1;
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.community:
                    if(checked){
                        score+=1;
                    }
                    break;
                    }
        }
```

This should be declared out side method `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Second declare variables int score = 0; and TextView output as class instance variables and not as onCreatemethods variables. What I mean is

```
public class check_Button extends Pop_sallian{
        int score = 0;
        TextView output = null;
```

This should solve your can not resolve score and output variable issue. But seriously I did not understand what are you trying to do :D You are displaying the value of score in output text in onCrateView (which gets called when activity is loaded) that means your score value is always zero :) and the when user clicks check box you are updating value of score :) only you know what will you do with that value :)

Free suggestion :P - If you want to display score after calculation of score move the display code inside onCheckboxClicked

```
    onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
                boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

                switch(view.getId()){
                    case R.id.concern:
                        if(checked) {
                            score += 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.faith:
                        if(checked){
                            score+=1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.respect:
                        if(checked){
                            score+=1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.education:
                        if(checked){
                            score+=1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.community:
                        if(checked){
                            score+=1;
                        }
                        break;
                  }
           if(score == 0){
              output.setText("Come on! Get involved, your la sallian community needs you.");
            } else if(score == 1){
                output.setText("Good start, keep going!");
            } else if(score == 2){
                output.setText("Room to improve but doing good!");
            } else if(score == 3){
                output.setText("Very good, others look up to you!");
            } else if(score == 4){
                output.setText("Wow, you really are an inspiration");
            } else if(score == 5){
                output.setText("Excellent! You're a leader in your la sallian community");
            } else{
                output.setText("Unknown");
            }
}
```

Try to indent the code for more clarity :) If you are using Android-studio use ctrl+alt+i :)

Last suggestion :) I really dont see any point in extending a your checkButton class with popSalian or whatever try extending it from normal Activity :) Hope My answer helped you :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Yeah, that was my original purpose: to do the calculations after the button is clicked.